# CONVERT NULL data type to decimal data type in mongodb compass

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, pymongo

I am trying to convert a field datatype from null to decimal.

I tried to covert in the following way:

```
db.Battery.update(
  {MAX_AH_DAILY_THROUGHPUT:{$type:10}},
  [{$set:{MAX_AH_DAILY_THROUGHPUT:{$toDecimal:"$MAX_AH_DAILY_THROUGHPUT"}}}],
  {multi:true}
);
```

In `MAX_AH_DAILY_THROUGHPUT` field all values are null, but as per requirement I need to convert the field type as decimal.

Can someone help me how to convert it into decimal.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not clear what is the value that you want in this field, is it `0` as decimal? If so, why are you using the current value?

Answer (score 0):

If the current value is `null`, you don't need to use it, just use:

```
db.Battery.update(
  {MAX_AH_DAILY_THROUGHPUT: {$type: 10}}, 
  [{$set: {MAX_AH_DAILY_THROUGHPUT: {$toDecimal: 0}}}],
  {multi:true})
```